# identity cloaker

Tags: adblock

If I use an ISP cloaker such as IdentityCloaker (in order to access BBC iPlayer), will it affect my use of AdBlock or AdBlockPlus? Does the AdBlcok extension only recognise me by the Google account, or by my ISP?

Answer (score 0):

Adblock Plus for Chrome isn't tied to your Google account, nor your ISP.

Also, there are no ads in iPlayer.